# Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found - "2018 error"

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am using php 7.0.10 in my wamp server
I am trying to upload videos to dailymotion using php sdk files.
When i run the script it is showing the output as in image link.
[phpunit error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2slcF.png)
Also using this code PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase also displaying same error.

Answer (score 0):

To upload a video with the dailymotion-sdk-php you have to include the Dailymotion class in your script as below:

```
require_once('Dailymotion.php');

// Instanciate the PHP SDK.
$api = new Dailymotion();

...
```

then you can follow this guide to upload your videos (you have code samples in php): [upload guide](https://developer.dailymotion.com/guides/upload)